# IPV6 ND router advert Malformed packet

Tags: networking, ipv6, icmp

Am trying to simulate IPv6 ND router Advertisement packet in openvswitch for one of my projects, but the formed packet is malformed(analyzed it in wireshark). Following is the packet dump I created,

```
ICPMV6 ND - Router Advertisement:
Mulicast dst-mac: 33:33:00:00:00:1
Router src-mac: 68:54:ed:00:00:06

00000000  33 33 00 00 00 01 68 54-ed 00 00 06 86 dd 60 00 |33....hT........|
00000010  00 00 40 00 3a dd fe 80-00 00 00 00 00 00 90 ff |..@.:...........|
00000020  02 25 fe 52 ef 00 ff 02-00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 |.%.R............|
00000030  00 00 00 01 00 00 86 00-2a 7a ff 00 28 23 86 00 |........*z..(#..|
00000040  00 00 86 00 00 00                               |......          |
```

can you guys please point out if am missing something
Appreciate the help.

Comment: What does wireshark tell you?  e.g. at which layer is the packet malformed?

Comment: At the Ethernet layer with error
"Expert Info (Error/Malformed): Malformed Packet (Exception occurred)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imported your hexdump into wireshark (cool - I just learned about that capability).  Here is what it looks like in my wireshark:

[image]

It looks like there are some fields you need to set up in the ICMPv6 header.  For an ND RA, according to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4861#section-4.2), the ICMP type should be 134 (0x86) and the code is 0.  The checksum will also need to be calculated correctly.

For the reference, here is the text I imported into wireshark 1.99.1 using the [`File` -> `Import from Hex Dump ...` menu](https://www.wireshark.org/docs/wsug_html_chunked/ChIOImportSection.html):

```
00000000  33 33 00 00 00 01 68 54 ed 00 00 06 86 dd 60 00  33....hT........ 
00000010  00 00 40 00 3a dd fe 80 00 00 00 00 00 00 90 ff  ..@.:........... 
00000020  02 25 fe 52 ef 00 ff 02 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  .%.R............ 
00000030  00 00 00 01 00 00 00 00 2a 7a ff 00 28 23 86 00  ........*z..(#.. 
00000040  00 00 86 00 00 00                                ......
```

Note no `-` between 7th and 8th hex bytes and no `|` surrounding ASCII bytes.

Comment: yes, I figured that, corrected the code now. Lets see if its works now. 
How did it work in your wireshark though ?

Comment: @vindyz Updated answer with what I needed to put in a text file to import in wireshark.  Not sure if this is how you are doing it or if you are capturing from an actual device.

Comment: oh I got it working , I was the - & | were causing problems. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @vindyz Sure, no problem - thanks for the green checkmark.  Don't forget to also upvote answers you find useful :)